# How to automate rsync in OS X with remote server

Tags: macos, rsync

My remote Server is samba server, which is accessible by both Mac and Windows machine.I created a common folder in Samba server. I want my local folder to be in sync with the common folder on my samba Server. Because when internet connection is lost i am unable to access the files copied to common folder.For that sake i want to sync my local folder with it.

My goals are:

1. When i remove files from local folder,it should get removed in common folder in samba server
2. Similarly when i modify or delete files in common folder, it should get reflected in local folder of my machine.

I tried rsync:

`rsync --progress -avzC --stats --force  Source root@remoteserver:/path`

*But how do I automate syncing from both sides?*

Note: For this i can rely on Dropbox, Boxsync or some cloud share app support. But i want to implement my own functionality, I don't want to rely on Third party API.

Comment: Use a cron job or a launchd job... https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/ScheduledJobs.html